# override session for a user (without user list)

Tags: session, lightdm

I have a machine that will be shared among few users and me.  The other users come from Windows environment; I think Xfce is great for them but for myself, I always want to use i3.

So the behavior I'm looking for is:

- If I log in, I want i3 to be selected,
- If anybody else logs in (even newly added account), they get Xfce4.

I found only 2 ways to do it:

- Enable user list, which does remember last choice per user,

  but I would like to avoid exposing the list (also user names are
  very short here so it's actually a lot faster to type them).
- Switch it manually every time,

  but this is cumbersome and if I forget to switch it back, poor folks
  get confused by i3.

Is it possible to override the selection for single user?  It would be OK even if my user setting just ignored the switch and always used i3 no matter what.

(This is Debian Jessie, stubbornly holding on to SysV init; using lightdm.  I'd be interested also in solution outside lightdm, though.)

Answer (score 5):

In `lightdm.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]
session-wrapper = /usr/local/bin/lightdm-session-wrapper
```

In `/usr/local/bin/lightdm-session-wrapper` if xfce4 is the default DE:

```
case "$USER" in
    you) i3 ;;
    *) $@ ;;
esac
```